# Motor Shield Needed or not?

Tags: arduino

To use [this 4WD Car](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-4wd-drive-aluminum-mobile-robot-platform-for-robot-arduino-uno-mega2560-r3-duemilanove-black.html) with Raspberry Pi, does it nee a motor shield?

Answer (score 2):

It will need something in order to drive 4 motors.  You options are to use an arduino with a shield that can drive 4 motors.  Or you can try and build an expansion for the PI that can drive 4 motors.  The Raspirobot board by Simon Monk will drive 2, but you could easily use an arudino with a shield and just communicate with it via serial from the PI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to turn the motors on and off individually, a [PicoBorg](http://piborg.org/picoborg) would provide a nice cheap Raspberry Pi addon capable of driving such motors (they look nearly identical to the ones we sell [here](http://piborg.org/accessories) for use with PicoBorgs).